# MVC CSS on view page (not _layout) not working

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a problem with MVC4 CSS.
i m including a CSS file named registration.css in an another view page named "registerUser.cshtml". This page is like a content page in mvc4 razor.
but problem is that CSS is not working.

How can i resolve this.
I have also included in BundleConfig.cs as

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/registration.css"));
```

But it is also not working. Help me.[image]

Comment: Use `@Style.Render('"~/Content/css")` instead of `.....css`

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

instead of

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/registration.css")
```

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer. Actually another css file from _Layout.cshtml overwrites the view page css file. when i removed main.css from Viewpage.cshtml, it works fine. Well, Thanks to all, thanks @Exception - u gave me important knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single css file on a page then use this :

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/registration.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

OR

If you want many css files on Layout Page or at any View Page then make it's bundle and include it in this way:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

You are using `@Styles.Render("~/Content/registration.css")` which is wrong..try above solution.

Comment: when i m using @Url.Content("~/Content/registration.css"), it sets double quotes values on the page. i mean it prints ~/Content/registration.css on the page.

Comment: <style type="text/css">@Url.Content("~/Content/registration.css")</style>  not working again

Comment: @Mayank..or write it as.... <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/registration.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: @Mayank..there will be problem somewhere else...<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/registration.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />...this will work perfectly...just check path of css file..

Comment: will i have to include this css file in _Layout.cshtml file or in RegisterUser.cshtml file ??

Comment: @Mayank..in browser where you are checking that css is loading or not just press ctrl+f5 sometimes css is loaded from browser cache also.

Comment: see, i ahve uploaded another image for css path.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: @Mayank...that is why problem is coming..you are giving wrong path to jquery files...

Comment: It seems you got two reference of JQuery in "registerUser.cshtml". One from _Layout.cshtml and one on the page itself.

Comment: i have removed all the jquery related errors from the page. Now what should i do ? because, css is again not working

Comment: this is not possible...just follow my first answer and include css on registerUser page..and refresh page in browser with ctrl+f5..@Mayank