# CSS not being pulled into page?

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller

I'm attempting to make a basic side navbar using Bootstrap 4 on a C# MVC project using the tutorial I found [here](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar). The project target framework is .Net 4.5.2. There's not a whole lot to this page at this moment so I posted the entire page below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Our Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<!-- Font Awesome JS -->
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
        </div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <p>Dummy Heading</p>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</div>

@RenderBody()
<!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Popper.JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what the page looks like when I run the code. It looks like the CSS is not being fully included or something. I'm a bit new to MVC but not to HTML. Is there a special way to get MVC to fully load in all JS and CSS files?

[image: Resulting page]

I can also see the JS and CSS for Bootstrap in the Chrome Console Source tab.

[image]

What am I missing here?

**EDIT 1**

I forgot to mention the HTML above is located on the _layout.cshtml file. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Have you looked at what's been downloaded (or not) using a tool like *Fiddler*

Comment: Check developer tools' console. Are there any errors there?

Comment: Oddly enough Fiddler crashes the application. Suddenly the Microsoft Login Page is throwing a "This site cannot be reached" error. If I stop the app, stop Fiddler, and restart the app it works just fine.

Comment: @OguzOzgul No errors on the Dev Tools' console.

Comment: When I run this html code on my machine, everything is downloaded just fine except your style.css file which I don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what's going on. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25260881/6827790) answer got me thinking that maybe I had the code in the wrong file. I pulled it from the layout.cshtml file and put it in the index.cshtml file and it started working!

[image]